# Is it possible to use another application(android) as a data source of any other application

Tags: android, database

We want to use an android app(not developed by us) as a data source for our app(developed by us). The user of our app will input the data, that data will be input to the app that we want to be our data source. There, data will be matched to the existing data in the app. If matched, the output will be displayed on the console of our app. 
The question is, it is possible to use other android app into the app you want to build such that your user will not know that the other app is working in the background. How would that be possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you own both applications you could create a content provider and open it up to the rest of the platform or you could do the same thing but require specific permission that one app creates and the other app requests. For more check out https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating

Comment: i dont own that application that i want to use as a data source but that application is free at playstore.

Comment: It sounds like what you need to do then is reach out to the developer who has created that application and ask them if the data in their app is available via a ContentProvider/ perhaps if not ask them to expose it via one. Or find out where their data is coming from and create your own client for that data.